# What’s the difference between מידת חסידות and לפנים משורת הדין?

Tags: midas-chasidus

The Gemera mentions the idea of לפנים משורת הדין ( for example: Brachot 7a, 45b, Ketuvot 97a, etc) and the Gemera also mentions מידת חסידות (for example: Shabbat 120a, Bava Metzia 52b, Chullin 130b etc). I am wondering, what is the difference between the two (if any)? Thanks

Comment: An action that is _lifnim mishurat hadin_ is a _middat chasidut_. That's how I've seen it used and always thought of it. It's a grammatical difference but both are serving the same idea

Comment: @Rabbi Kaii a source would be nice :)

Comment: @שלום I dont see Tosfoat talking about Midat Chassidut there?

Comment: Isn't your BM 52b demonstrating it? The _middat chassidut_ is taught in reference to doing something not required. Same with Chullin and Shabbat. What sort of source do you need other than that?

Comment: @RabbiKaii fair point

Comment: @RabbiKAii I'd think to formulate it that middas hachassidus is a middah, whereas lifnim mishuras hadin is an action. So you HAVE middas hachassidus and act in accordance, and DO lifnim mishuras hadin. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2):

It would seem that לפנים משורת הדין applies in a case where either the sages obligated us to do so - based on the Mitzvah of ״ועשית הישר והטוב״, or if there is a reason for this case to be an exception - e.g. the person is of high stature, like the Rambam writes (יסודי התורה ה:יא), or if it is a case where most people are obligated - only you have a “Heter” - e.g. either an elderly person or someone of high stature, who returns a lost item, even though he is exempt (see Tosafos Bava Metzia 24b)

Comment: So your saying that לפנים משורת הדין is something were obligated in (based off the pasuk), and מידת חסידות is something we are not obligated in yet the righteous do it, is that correct?